# How to add reviews and rating to each record (clinic) on webpage, that is store in the database?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I want to add reviews and rating to each (clinic) record of the database. If people search a clinic, the webpage shows multiple (clinics) records on the webpage, and then user can rate and write review to any clinic or multiple clinics. Then each clinic will show there won rating stars.

Like in this link

http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=Quiet+Italian+Restaurant%2C+SF&fr=mkg063&ei=UTF-8

User can give different rat and write different reviews to any record like 1, 2, and 3 mentions in above link. Please help me, I will appreciate.
I am using php, html, javascript and mysql.

Comment: This question is too broad. Do some tutorials with storing data, reviewing systems, and come back when you have specific questions about the implementation.

Comment: We help you on specific problems, not build it all for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty broad, but the concepts are roughly equivalent to a CMS system.  Content goes in (your reviews)  Content goes out (displaying reviews from DB)  User login system, and some sort of mechanism to allow the user to find records.

A previous version of this book/article is what helped get me into application development on the PHP side.  http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/php-amp-mysql-1-installation  It's got all the basics, the rest is up to you.